# Google fonts web site works with special char, but web site is not

Tags: html, css, fonts

When I check a font in Google Fonts preview page all special chars are working as expected, but when the font is used in a web site some chars are printed with the default font.
Is there any trick to get the font working to the fullest in the browsers too?

Example here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yaardm

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=IM+Fell+DW+Pica+SC');
p{font-family: 'IM Fell DW Pica SC', sans-serif;}
h1{font-family: 'IM Fell DW Pica SC', sans-serif;}
...
<p>These are working: a ö ä ø</p>
<p>These are not: ā &#x101;</p>
```

If I enter the same special characters in the preview, they are all working. The chars **"a ö ä ø ā"** can be tested in the preview box here: https://fonts.google.com/specimen/IM+Fell+DW+Pica

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A colleague found that my characters are not part of latin and the font didn't support them. The Google Fonts preview will try another font in the background and that's why it looks like it is working. By manually defining the font I got the "Kahako A" as I wanted.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yaapKw

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'IM Fell DW Pica script=all rev=6';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src:   url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/l/font?kit=xBKKJV4z2KsrtQnmjGO17HM30v831NPLrMTMWjZhJsgljegwSeDbtiHKgT6kSuH8OhAwGXnQZ2fim__WzpJMvT-ot7WhoQNhxW9XSHPUr95hxaMfyGAgGEujUXva07BSgdd4-sq5HMlny4sZVjdTlXcwcWdsnk25xubTXmsZQe5_f2oRvW8cxG4bMB_YmvaR96xlbbE5D7Gw2o7jubnkMA&skey=2798f34675f18639&v=v6) format('woff2');
}
...
font-family: 'IM Fell DW Pica script=all rev=6', sans-serif;
```